# Automated testing via Burp Suite

Tags: java, android, testing, scripting, burp

I use **Burp Suite** to testing my application, but every request send manually and it isn't comfortable. Can I automate my test cases some way? Is it possible to use java scripts in **Burp Suite Repeater** (or via another extension)? For example script send first request, parse response, then send second one which depends on first. Any other language except java ?

Comment: What you are looking for is already available in the Enterprise version.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I have never used this version. Could you give some more information about automated testing in Enterprise?

Comment: Please check [this](https://portswigger.net/burp) page.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the Burp Suite Intruder or Scanner option for automating your testing.

Here are the respective links: 
https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/tools/intruder/using
https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/scanner

You could also use sqlmap and point it to your Burpsuite, like this:

sqlmap -r test.raw --proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8080

For more sqlmap information: http://manpages.org/sqlmap